# Regex retrieving a variable string from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, variables

If I have a string like

```
ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 vrid 0
```

pool-group is a variable that I want to retrieve and store into a string variable.

pool1 - pool3 are also variables that I want to store into an array list but there can be any number of them and arent necessarily named pool*

I want to capture pool-group and all the pools

I want to use regex to do this but am unable to get it working

Comment: so what _exactly_ is the question? You want to capture every word after `ip nat`?

Comment: Show what you have tried, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might want something like:

```
>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'ip nat (\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+) vrid 0', s)
>>> print m.groups()
('pool-group', 'pool1', 'pool2', 'pool3')
>>> print m.group(1)
pool-group
```

This will search for 'ip nat ' followed by four groups of non-whitespace, with at least one whitespace char between. This should be suitably generic, so long as the pool variables never contain space/tab.

Edit:

```
>>> s = 'ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 vrid 0'
>>> t = 'ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 pool6 pool7 vrid 0'
>>> m = re.search('^ip nat (.*) vrid 0', s)
>>> print m.groups()
('pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3',)
>>> n = re.search('^ip nat (.*) vrid 0', t)
>>> print n.groups()
('pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 pool6 pool7',)
```

Comment: what if I dont know how many pools are going to be entered. e.g. it could be 3 or 5

Comment: Well, if there are only two possible outcomes (3 or 5), you can create two specfic regex's and test them both. Or you could have one with 3 matching groups plus two optional matching groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for,

```
>>> s = "ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 vrid 0"
>>> m = re.search(r'pool-\S+', s)
>>> f = m.group()
>>> f
'pool-group'
>>> lst = re.findall(r'pool\d+', s)
>>> lst
['pool1', 'pool2', 'pool3']
```

OR

```
>>> m = re.search(r'\w+-\w+', s)
>>> f = m.group()
>>> f
'pool-group'
>>> lst = re.findall(r'\w+\d+', s)
>>> lst
['pool1', 'pool2', 'pool3']
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if pool-group and pool could be any arbitrary name?

Comment: @megazero see the update. I donno what do you mean by arbitary names.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split by space and grab the items you want from the resulted list:

```
line = "ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 vrid 0"
arr = line.split(' ')
print arr # prints ['ip', 'nat', 'pool-group', 'pool1', 'pool2', 'pool3', 'vrid', '0']
```

And if you want to use regex:

```
import re
line = "ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 vrid 0"
arr = re.split('\s', line)
print arr # prints ['ip', 'nat', 'pool-group', 'pool1', 'pool2', 'pool3', 'vrid', '0']

# and you can also do the following:
print arr[3:6] # prints ['pool1', 'pool2', 'pool3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x="ip nat pool-group pool1 pool2 pool3 vrid 0" 
pattern=re.compile(r"ip nat (.*?) vrid 0")
print pattern.findall(x)
```

This will give all the pools irrespective of their count.Hope this helps.